# How to pass preprocessor macros / functions to cl.exe?

Tags: visual-c++, devenv

I can pass a constant with a value:

`cl.exe /D"NAME=VALUE"`

But how can I pass a macro function (e.g. `#define FOO(x) (x+4)`? The following doesn't work:

`cl.exe /D"FOO(x)=(x*4)"
cl.exe /D"FOO(x) (x*4)"`

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Port to MSVC from GCC where this works and is used.